# How can I place capistrano stages into a sub-directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, capistrano3

By default, the capistrano stages are placed in `/config/deploy/`. I have a ton of stages here. I'd also like to have some of my stages grouped like `/config/deploy/group1/` and `/config/deploy/group2`. How could I include multiple paths?

I noticed you could set this:

```
set :stage_config_path, 'cap/stages'
```

But I need it to look recursively at config/deploy instead of only in that folder.

It would be nice if I could even do things like:

```
$ cap group1/stage1 deploy
```

How would I go about accomplishing this in my Ruby on Rails application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to override some Capistrano methods to get this to work. I wrote the following code at the top of my `Capfile`:

```
module Capistrano
  module DSL
    module Stages

      def stages
        names = Dir[stage_definitions].map { |f| "#{File.dirname(f)}/#{File.basename(f, ".rb")}".gsub("#{stage_config_path.to_s}/", '') }
        assert_valid_stage_names(names)
        names
      end

      # Override stage_definitions to include subfolders
      def stage_definitions
        stage_config_path.join("**/*.rb")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**Explanation**

By overriding the `#stage_definitions` method, I added `**/` to that it would look for the `.rb` files in sub directories.

The next issue was that `capistrano/setup.rb` had this line of code:

```
load stage_config_path.join("#{stage}.rb")
```

That means I need `stage` to include the folder name. Then I overrode `#stages` so that the `names` variable would be an array of stages, including the subdirectory if any. Example:

```
config/
├── deploy/
│   ├── group_1/
|   ├──   ├── stage1.rb
│   ├── stage2.rb
│   ├── stage3.rb
```

Becomes:

```
['group_1/stage1', 'stage2', 'stage3']
```

That allows the Rake tasks to be created and load the files correctly!

```
$ cap group_1/stage1 deploy
```